# GAS - Comparing Emails or Threads

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, compare

I'm making a google script that sends certain emails to a spreadsheet. I'm want the script to run every few minutes, but I want it to skip emails it already added to the document.
Is there a way in gmail to compare emails? to know which came before?

Thank you, 
Chaim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you can take.

1. Store the message id of the email that you have already processed. You can either store it in ScriptDb or in another spreadsheet.
2. You can add the message to a particular label, say "Processed". And change your script to only work on the messages that do not have the "Processed" label.

Comment: Yes, you can make an array. And in Javascript you can use the == operator to compare strings. See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: For future readers, note that [ScriptDB was sunset on Dec 18, 2014](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/sunset) and this was noted [here](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2014/05/deprecating-scriptdb-and-domain-service.html).  Some alternatives are suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450003/scriptdb-replacement)