# ScriptDB Replacement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a script that looks something like this:

```
function clearDatabase() 
{
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
     while (true) {
       var result = db.query({}); 
      if (result.getSize() == 0) 
        {
          break;
        }
     while (result.hasNext()) {
      db.remove(result.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Please pardon my wreck of formatting. What should I replace the ScriptDb with? I know it has been depreciated, and I also know that it doesn't have a direct replacement. Is there a way to keep the function without having to use CloudSQL?

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't many data to store you can use a sheet for store information or a dedicated spreadsheet :
[Google apps script and script db replacement example needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397220/google-apps-script-and-script-db-replacement-example-needed)

A cleaner solution could be use Google Cloud SQL (but not free) or a combination of App Engine Datastore (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) and Cloud endpoint (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks) : you call your endpoint from app script for store data in app engine.